# Bicubic interpolation in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I'm trying to do bicubic interpolation on a `torch.Tensor`.

I know about `torch.nn.functional.interpolate`, but that method doesn't support bicubic interpolation yet.

I know that `PIL` images support bicubic interpolation, so I created this snippet (part of torch.nn.Module).

```
def build_transform(self, shape):
    h, w = shape[2] * self.scale_factor, shape[3] * self.scale_factor
    return Compose([
        ToPILImage(),
        Resize((h, w), interpolation=PIL.Image.BICUBIC),
        ToTensor()
      ])

def forward(self, x: Tensor):
    if self.transform is None:
        self.transform = self.build_transform(x.shape)

    shape = x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] * self.scale_factor, x.shape[3] * self.scale_factor
    new = Tensor(size=shape, device=x.device)

    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        new[i] = self.transform(x[i])
    new.requires_grad_()

    return new
```

My assumption is that this method is slower than interpolating the `Tensor` in one pass.

**My Question:** Is there no other way to compute this without the loop? I assume that the difference would be noticeable (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: gradients do not flow through this function. why not use the `Resize` transform as part of the augmentations your dataset is doing when loading the images?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that because the loading is common for all architectures I have. I would have to use some parameter to signal the upscale, but I wanted to know. if there's no other way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

torch.nn.functional.interpolate() with mode='bicubic' is supported since pytorch 1.2.0.